# Constantly need to reset django local settings module

Tags: django, settings

I have made two settings files, one for local testing and one for production (heroku). Every time I pull and start working locally I need to run the following two commands for it to work:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectName.settings_local
```

Without doing so I get the error that the local settings module cannot be found. This error appeared after I tried to have both settings files in a settings folder, which I did not get to work so I put them back in the original place. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: the command you're running is telling the software where to find your settings and it's standard procedure for using multiple settings.py files. The first line is also unnecessary, as the second line will always override the export. Now, please clarify how you want to run your project, and we could offer you better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wsgi.py file setdefault settings file path, in your case local setting file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectName.settings_local")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

You may also need to add in manage.py file

```
.....
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectName.settings_local")
    .......
```

I hope this will help you.